# Embed CASE inside CONCAT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have problems in `CASE WHEN` and `CONCAT` clause, this one:

```
 WHEN
   'nvarchar' 
THEN
   CONCAT(column_name, ' ', 'varchar', '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')', 
   CASE
      ISNULLABLE 
      WHEN
         'NO' 
      THEN
         ' not null' , ',')
```

You see I have additional `CASE` inside `CONCAT`, if there is `ISNULLABLE` result `NO` then I want to put also text `' not null'` to the entire `CONCAT` output.

Nevertheless I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Entire code:

```
SELECT
    table_schema,
    column_name,
    CASE data_type 
       WHEN 'nvarchar' 
          THEN CONCAT(column_name, ' ', 'varchar', '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')', 
                      CASE ISNULLABLE 
                         WHEN 'NO' THEN ' not null' , ',') 
       WHEN 'datetime2' 
          THEN CONCAT(column_name, ' ', 'timestamp', ',') 
       ELSE CONCAT(column_name, ' ', data_type, ' ') 
    END AS 'Postgres', IS_NULLABLE 
FROM
    information_schema.columns;
```

Comment: You misspelled `IS_NULLABLE`. And what do you mean with `' not null' , ','`?

Comment: `...THEN ' not null' , ',') WHEN...`? What does `, ',')` mean in that context? Should `' not null'` be inside some function?

Comment: ok i corrected this should be :    WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN CONCAT(column_name, ' ', 'varchar', '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')',     CASE IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'NO' THEN ' not null' END , ',')

Comment: @HoneyBadger this is to construct script for postgres, to not make monkey job creating tables and types

Comment: Also - `when 'nvarchar' then 'varchar` - Is this deliberate?

Comment: Close the _inner_ CASE expression by inserting `END` between `' not null'` and `,`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to end the inner case statement.
Also, you misspelled `IS_NULLABLE`

```
CASE data_type
    WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN CONCAT(column_name, ' ', 'varchar', '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')',  CASE IS_NULLABLE WHEN 'NO' THEN ' not null' ELSE 'nullable' END          , ',')
    WHEN 'datetime2' THEN   CONCAT(column_name, ' ',  'timestamp', ',')  
    ELSE  CONCAT(column_name, ' ',  data_type, ' ')
END AS 'Postgres' ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   table_schema,
   column_name,
   CASE data_type 
      WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 
        CONCAT(column_name, ' ', 'varchar', '(', CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, ')', CASE IS_NULLABLE  WHEN 'NO' THEN ' not null' END,  ',')
      WHEN 'datetime2' THEN 
        CONCAT(column_name, ' ', 'timestamp', ',') 
      ELSE 
        CONCAT(column_name, ' ', data_type, ' ') 
   END AS 'Postgres', IS_NULLABLE 
FROM
   information_schema.columns;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this below re organized CONCAT/CASE statement-

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
    column_name, 
    ' ', 
    CASE 
        WHEN data_type = 'nvarchar' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN CONCAT('varchar(',CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(20)),') not null,')
        WHEN data_type = 'nvarchar' AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN CONCAT('varchar(',CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(20)),'),')
        WHEN data_type = 'datetime2' THEN CONCAT('timestamp', ',') 
        ELSE CONCAT(data_type, ' ')
    END, 
    ' '
) AS 'Postgres'
FROM
information_schema.columns;
```